# Shalosh Seudos on Friday Night

Tags: shabbat, meal-seudah, leil-shabbat

Is there anything wrong with having the third meal on Friday night instead of the following day (i.e. two on friday night and one the next day)? Is one still yotzei 3 Seudos?

This would be especially useful in the winter months where Shabbos ends quite early.

Comment: Similarly, what about loading all 3 on the morning, or some other irregular combination of time slots and meals?

Comment: @WAF Indeed, although wouldn't that would imply some sort of fasting?

Comment: I have seen a very respected posek washing by Kiddush after an early minyan and then having his second day meal later at home as his seuda shlishis but the best scenario this time of year is to daven early and eat the first meal early, then you will have some appetite for seuda shlishis closer to sundown. If you can't, then I refer you to what I saw this posek do. (I asked him about it)

Comment: I think you mean the second meal on Friday night.

Comment: @DoubleAA I guess there are two ways to look at it. Yes, the second meal, but the third in the context of the entire Shabbos obligation.

Comment: But there is a big Nafka Mina in terms of which if any of the meals you could [arguably] use mezonot/fruit for!

Comment: @DoubleAA in which case, I stand by my original intentions. The "lighter" meal should be the one later that night.

Comment: It's much harder to defend out-of-order meals than wrongly timed meals. Consider quickly why having regular kiddush in shul shabbat morning does not count as your 3rd meal if not for problems of order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seudah Shlishis has a specific time it should be done, which is roughly Shabbos afternoon (preferably after praying Mincha, but can even be eaten after the time for Mincha has arrived.) [See Shulhan Aruch, 291, 2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14325&st=&pgnum=78). The SA in [OC 289](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14325&st=&pgnum=77) has a whole section on the laws of the Shabbos morning meal. The fact that the rule of *Kiddush Bimakom Seudah* still applies for this seudah clearly indicates a time frame for the day meal on Shabbos as being in the morning. I do not see how one is to avoid the obligation of two *seudos* on the day of Shabbos, *lechatehilah*.

Comment: I wonder: if you don't eat anything in the morning (and missed the opportunity to eat the "second" meal), is there still a chiyuv kiddush in the afternoon?