# Eating two consecutive meals on Shabbat Erev Pesach and Seudah Shlishit

Tags: shabbat, passover, meal-seudah

When Erev Pesach was on Shabbat, nearly every shul rav I have encountered has advised this procedure on Shabbat morning:

Daven very early so that Shabbat davening will end before the last time one is allowed to eat *chametz*.

Go home, wash and eat a meal with challah. Then bentch, and wash again and eat another meal with challah. This way, you will have eaten your 3 Shabbat meals all with *challah*.

I have read that one may fulfill *Se'udah Shlishit* eating fruit and one may also eat *matza ashirah* on Erev Pesach. For some reason, the rabbis insist that all 3 meals should have challah / chametz.

Considering [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4090/5275) that explains that *Seudah Shlishit* must be eaten in the afternoon, which, in this case, would be after the time one would be allowed to eat *chametz*, how do these rabbis suggestions accomplish having the 3rd meal immediately after the second, as they suggest?

Comment: You may find https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76809/what-is-technically-required-for-shalosh-seudas/76813#76813 enlightening

Answer (score 2):

*Magen Avraham* ([OC 444:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2172)) writes that one should split his morning meal into two meals, because there are opinions who hold that one can fulfill his obligation of eating three meals by doing so.